# DDD Value Objects and Entity Without ORM Mapping in PHP

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, orm, entity, value-object

First, as I know, Entity in DDD is almost same with Value Object except Entity has identity. Every article I have read say same thing that entity id has ORM mapping with any ORM tool. But I don’t want to use ORM mapping in Entity. Instead, I would like to do database operation with Repository Interfaces without mapping. And, in this case, I am stuck on how I should do this.

I will explain in my mind with an example below

Let’s assume I have a TODO application and there are some questions in the TODO and some answers in each those questions.

We have 3 value object (or entity):
Todo
TodoQuestion
TodoQuestionValue

Now, I thought that I have a value object (or entity) for TODO. This value object has a method to get questions that gets array of TodoQuestion value object. And inside of TodoQuestion value object we have a method to get values of questions that gets array of TodoQuestionValue.

```php
<?php
class Todo{
   private int $id;
   /**
    * @param array<TodoQuestion> $questions
    */
   private array $questions;
   private TodoRepositoryInterface $repository;
   public function __constructor(TodoRepositoryInterface $repository){
      $this->repository = $repository;
   }
   public function getQuestions(){
      $this->questions = $this->repository->listQuestionsByTodoId($this->id);
   }
}
```

```php
<?php
class TodoQuestion{
   private int $id;
   private string $question;
   /**
    * @param array<TodoQuestionValue> $values
    */
   private array $values;
   private TodoRepositoryInterface $repository;
   public function __constructor(TodoRepositoryInterface $repository){
      $this->repository = $repository;
   }
   public function getValues(){
      $this->values = $this->repository->listValuesByQuestionId($this->id);
   }
}
```

Now, I would like to get your opinions about how I could shape this structure by following the DDD rules.

Thank you.

Comment: _"I would like to do database operation with Repository Interfaces without mapping"_ In this context, "mapping" refers to the relation between a database column and a property in your entity/model (whether it's automatic or manual is irrelevant - it's still a mapping). It's unclear what exactly you mean by "without mapping". You've shown the intended interface of your repository, but how are you going to implement it, if not by mapping database columns to entity/model properties? Repositories and ORMs are not orthogonal concepts, if anything they tend to work hand in hand.

Comment: The thing I was trying to tell is that I don't want to use any dependency while using Entity and VO. And I'd like to know what the best way to make db stuff in DDD using Entity,VO etc. is. In my example, I wrote a method to get questions of TODO in Entity(or VO - I am not sure), and is it right way to do that?

Comment: @FurkanKolcu: My question isn't how you intend to interact with your repository, but rather how you intend to **implement** your repository. If not using an ORM, are you not effectively asking how to roll your own custom (lightweight) ORM? Because that's quite the undertaking.